# Can't access cross VM of different zones

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine

I have 2 VM instances using the same network(default), same subnet (default), but in 2 different zones. I accessed the VM and then ping to another VM but they did not resolve! What do I have to do to make them communicate? Below is the information of the system:

> Network:
>    - Name: default
>
> Subnet:
>    - Name: default
>    - Network: default
>    - Ip range: 10.148.0.0/20
>    - Region: asia-southeast1
>
> VM1:
>    - Subnet: default
>    - IP: 10.148.0.54
>    - Zone: asia-southeast1-c
>
> VM2:
>    - Subnet: default
>    - IP: 10.148.0.56
>    - Zone: asia-southeast1-b

Please help me! thank you!

Comment: Looking at the discussion in the answer bellow, I am not sure if you still have the issue between VMs.
Are you using only 1 network interface? Does the connectivity work when using IPs?  
For the error message you are seeing, check the details on this page regarding NXDOMAIN:
https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#query-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the ARP is resolved for the remote VM you want to ping.

Also check if there is a firewall rule for the default network blocking the communication between the VM's.

Comment: Hello @Vivekanada
Thank for your answer! I tried checking ARP with **nslookup instance-2** command, and as a result it didn't find instance: `** server could not find instance-2: NXDOMAIN`. But i'm ping to instance-2 via it ip address and it works fine!